# Best place to save data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using Clean Architecture in Flutter with Getx as State Management.
I have a list that i am taking from backend and i am showing it in UI and user can do some changes to this list as well.
where is the best place to store the data that is taken from backend and show from and change data.

right now in this example
the data is stored in Getx Controller.is this approach correct?or there is a better way?

```
class Controller extends GetxController{
  
  List<Data> lsData = [];
  
  fetchApi()async{
    lsData = await fetchApi();
    update();
  }
  
  add(Data data){
    lsData.add(data);
    update();
  }
  
  postApi()async{
    await post(lsData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer this sample code for GetX controller. https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to save data in flutter, if you want to save data local there is  Hive(i like this), Share preference, SQlite,GetX Storage and more
if you want to save data online I recommend Firestore

Hope this can be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks but i do not have  any intention to save the data in any local database